# Runge-Kutta oscillate and does not converging

Tags: c, runge-kutta

I would like to integrate a differential equation using Runge-Kutta 4. The equations do not depend on time. When doing the integration, I don't get the correct value.

The right side of my equation is obtained by entering the variables by reference to a function. This function is correct since I have integrated it using cvode and I have obtained the correct result.

The right-side function is (the equation does not depends on time only of f00 variables)

```
RightSideEq(f00, ArGk1);
```

In that case, f00 are the variables and ArGk1 are the values of the right-hand side. For example, in that case, the differential equation is:

```
     df/dt = ArGk1.
```

```c
int main {
  
  int numberparticles = 6;
  double dt = 0.01;
  double f00[3*numberparticles];
  double FieldLK1[3*numberparticles],FieldLK2[3*numberparticles],FieldLK3[3*numberparticles],FieldLK4[3*numberparticles];
  double ArGk1[3*numberparticles],ArGk2[3*numberparticles],ArGk3[3*numberparticles],ArGk4[3*numberparticles];
  
  
  // Initial condition
  
  for (int k = 0; k < numberparticles; k++)
  {
    f00[3*k] = 0.1;
    f00[3*k+1] =0.2;
    f00[3*k+2]= 0.9;
  }
  
  //Iterate 100 times the Runge Kutta
  for (int i = 1; i < 100; i++)
  {
    
    // Initialize variable with 0. The variables FieldLK1, FieldLK2, FieldLK3 and FieldLK4 
    //correspond to the variables k1,k2,k3 and k4 defined on [wikipedia][1]
    
    for (int zp = 0; zp < numberparticles; zp++)
    {
      FieldLK1[3*zp]=0;
      FieldLK1[3*zp+1]=0;
      FieldLK1[3*zp+2]=0;
      
      FieldLK2[3*zp]=0;
      FieldLK2[3*zp+1]=0;
      FieldLK2[3*zp+2]=0;
      
      FieldLK3[3*zp]=0;
      FieldLK3[3*zp+1]=0;
      FieldLK3[3*zp+2]=0;
      
      FieldLK4[3*zp]=0;
      FieldLK4[3*zp+1]=0;
      FieldLK4[3*zp+2]=0;
      
      ArGk1[3*zp]=0;
      ArGk1[3*zp+1]=0;
      ArGk1[3*zp+2]=0;
      
      ArGk2[3*zp]=0;
      ArGk2[3*zp+1]=0;
      ArGk2[3*zp+2]=0;
      
      ArGk3[3*zp]=0;
      ArGk3[3*zp+1]=0;
      ArGk3[3*zp+2]=0;
      
      ArGk4[3*zp]=0;
      ArGk4[3*zp+1]=0;
      ArGk4[3*zp+2]=0;
    }
    
    RightSideEq(f00, ArGk1);
    
    for (int j = 0; j < numberparticles; j++)
    {
      FieldLK1[3*j]=  ArGk1[3*j];
      FieldLK1[3*j+1]= ArGk1[3*j+1];
      FieldLK1[3*j+2]= ArGk1[3*j+2];
      
      ArGk2[3*j] =   f00[3*j]  +0.5*FieldLK1[3*j]*dt;
      ArGk2[3*j+1] = f00[3*j+1]+0.5*FieldLK1[3*j+1]*dt;
      ArGk2[3*j+2] = f00[3*j+2]+0.5*FieldLK1[3*j+2]*dt;
    }
    
    RightSideEq(ArGk2, FieldLK2);
    
    for (int j = 0; j < numberparticles; j++)
    {
      ArGk3[3*j] =   f00[3*j]  +0.5*FieldLK2[3*j]*dt;
      ArGk3[3*j+1] = f00[3*j+1]+0.5*FieldLK2[3*j+1]*dt;
      ArGk3[3*j+2] = f00[3*j+2]+0.5*FieldLK2[3*j+2]*dt;
    }
    
    RightSideEq(ArGk3, FieldLK3);
    
    
    for (int j = 0; j < numberparticles; j++)
    {
      ArGk4[3*j] =   f00[3*j]  +FieldLK3[3*j]*dt;
      ArGk4[3*j+1] = f00[3*j+1]+FieldLK3[3*j+1]*dt;
      ArGk4[3*j+2] = f00[3*j+2]+FieldLK3[3*j+2]*dt;
    }
    
    RightSideEq(ArGk4, FieldLK4);
    
    
    for (int kk = 0; kk < numberparticles; kk++)
    {
      f00[3*kk] =   f00[3*kk]  +1.0/6.0*dt*(FieldLK1[3*kk]  +2.0*FieldLK2[3*kk]+2.0*FieldLK3[3*kk]  +FieldLK4[3*kk]);
      f00[3*kk+1] = f00[3*kk+1]+1.0/6.0*dt*(FieldLK1[3*kk+1]+2.0*FieldLK2[3*kk+1]+2.0*FieldLK3[3*kk+1]+FieldLK4[3*kk+1]);
      f00[3*kk+2] = f00[3*kk+2]+1.0/6.0*dt(FieldLK1[3*kk+2]+2.0*FieldLK2[3*kk+2]+2.0*FieldLK3[3*kk+2]+FieldLK4[3*kk+2]);
      
    }}
     return(0);
          }
```

The problem is that the code approaches the value that I expect to obtain and then oscillates around some value. I have tried to reduce the step size but I get the same result. I have never programmed a Runge Kutta algorithm or any similar code, but I would like to learn how to do it. If anyone has a suggestion I would appreciate it.

Thanks

Comment: Minor: `//Iterate 100 times the Runge Kutta   for (int i = 1; i < 100; i++)` is off by 1.  Iterates 99 times.

Comment: Small idea, try `double dp = 100;` and `*dt` --> `/dp`

Comment: You did not address any of the issues of the [now deleted first version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68877579) of this question. The naming of variables is not logical, but otherwise the provided code looks correct, up to the missing multiplication sign in the line `f00[3*kk+2] = ...`

Comment: Further, without some information on the right-side function (like an estimate for the Lipschitz constant) it is not possible to say what the error is caused by, the most likely guessed cause is that the step size `dt` is too large, see for instance https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1210698/maximum-timestep-for-rk4, or less related https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1633463/step-size-in-eulers-forward

Comment: This, or the code in the deleted question, is not the code that you actually run, as the mentioned error will give a compiler error. Thus it is impossible to tell if there are any other errors in the code that you actually run.